# How to buffer increasing/decreasing population zones?

Tags: python, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, arcgis-desktop

I will find out the difference in population between year 2000 and 2013. I have a feature class file with the population in year 2000 and 2013 that are connected to the municipal number and that is a point theme. What I want is to have buffer zones around each point and the size of the buffer zone to be determined by the number of residents that each point has. If the population has increased the buffer zone will get a red color and where the population has decreased the buffer zone will be blue. Is there anyone who can help me with this? Whether as a model in ModelBuilder, Python or a Toolbox.

Comment: This is easy to do as buffers but personally I would use graduated symbology. Is this just for display or do you need buffer polygons for something else?

Comment: Based on the question, user15888 only wants to represent increase or decrease, so graduated symbol is not necessary here.

Comment: You may be right so I'll await asker's clarification before answering.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need the following fields in your feature class
MunicipalNumber
2000_population
2013_population
diff_population = 2013_population-2000_population

Then as PolyGeo mentioned you would use graduated simbology based on the diff_population field

I see no case for using buffers here